# Has a spend from a hybrid public key ever made it to the blockchain?

Tags: public-key

If so, could you please give the TXID of a transaction that spends from a [hybrid public key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/57855/38618)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, there's a number of UTXO entries for the obscure hybrid key format. The transaction [657aecafe66d729d2e2f6f325fcc4acb8501d8f02512d1f5042a36dd1bbd21d1](https://blockstream.info/tx/657aecafe66d729d2e2f6f325fcc4acb8501d8f02512d1f5042a36dd1bbd21d1?expand) makes a number of interesting P2PK outputs, two each of which are `0x06` and `0x07` respectively.

```
OP_PUSHBYTES_65 06da9be28d6e6266ddc0bc71b09032f3a810ffc917b5876e23a03c118f24f6a84dae4a9a5244fbf47860bc0760102d6bde6257bfcb7155d3dd66b97181119f98c5 OP_CHECKSIG

OP_PUSHBYTES_65 07d19ef6ba5b92b87078dba3a00df392efc16917defb2be08f22e41ce2873335705bff95fed463550f291d3b1fd559af11e432256a47e738572be3b74fc6f73ed0 OP_CHECKSIG
```

None are spent, but there's no technical reason for this, the outputs are valid.

Comment: Looks like a good way to waste btc on fees by adding more bytes to your transaction to me ;-)